# Mute sound (A-frame)

Tags: javascript, audio, aframe

I made an a-scene with an a-videosphere. I try to enable/disable my sound with an button, but it dosn´t work some ideas? Here my code:

```
     var gargamel = 0;

    function mute_it() {
         gargamel += 1;

         if(gargamel == 1) {
          sound_off();
         }

         if(gargamel == 2) {
           sound_on();
           gargamel = 0;
         }
       }

       function sound_off() {
         $("#sound_button").attr("src","#soicon_off_src");
         $("intro").prop('muted', true);
       }

       function sound_on() {
          $("#sound_button").attr("src","#soicon_on_src");
          $("intro").prop('muted', false);
       }

     <a-assets timeout="0">
        <img id="soicon_on_src" src="footage/bilder/icon_mute.png" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <img id="soicon_off_src" src="footage/bilder/icon mute withoutsound.png" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <video id="intro" style="display:none" preload="none"
                   loop="false" crossorigin="anonymous" playsinline webkit-playsinline>
     </a-assets>

    <a-image id="sound_button" src="#soicon_on_src" onclick="mute_it()"></a-image>
```

Comment: Does the click event fire and call your method as expected? Better if you share a complete runnable example

Comment: works now thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh crap im stupid. there was a mistake

```
 $("intro").prop('muted', true);
 $("intro").prop('muted', false);
```

must be:

```
 $("video").prop('muted', true);
 $("video").prop('muted', false);
```

it looks like this code dosn´t mute the video with the id="intro" its mutes all videos(or only the one which plays). :)